# POST request in postman got 307, unable to reproduce in restassured

Tags: java, http-post, postman, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have a POST request, which I tried first in Postman, I wanted to capture the status code before it's redirected. In Postman, I got 307 (I set the settings so it doesn't follow redirects).

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiB3I.png)

But when I tried using restassured, it still got redirected, so I got 200 status code instead of 307.

Tried the same way with GET request with 302 status code, and that one works.

```
public void postDataBeforeLogin() {
    
    //post data before login
    Response response = RestAssured.given().redirects().follow(false).post("/data");
    
    assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), 307); 

}
```

I read an article/post about restassured not redirecting POST requests, but it was from 3 years ago, so I'm not sure if that is still the case.

Can anyone help/clarify?

Help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`RestAssuredConfig` will meet your requirements, like this:

```java
given().config(RestAssured.config().redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(false))).
```

in your case:

```java
import static io.restassured.config.RedirectConfig.redirectConfig;

Response response = RestAssured.given()
                    .config(RestAssured.config().redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(false)))
                    .post("/data");
```

See more: [REST-assured wiki](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#detailed-configuration)

It's recommended to **statically import** methods, see [this](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#static-imports)

Comment: 'redirectConfig() is undefined' error message on my end, is there something i should define first, or extra dependencies? a quick google search tells me it's already in restassured. thank you!

Comment: @Far `redirectConfig()` is a staic method, so you need static import its class `import static io.restassured.config.RedirectConfig.redirectConfig;`

Comment: ok imported and used the code, but it's still coming up as 200 and not 307 like it's showing up in postman :(

Comment: Sorry to say that I have no idea now, and I have no way to debug the code further.

Comment: that's alright, i learned about config, so thank you for the help!